# Weird function return value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return-value

I am trying to remove everything between curly braces in a string, and trying to do that recursivesly.
And I am returning `x` here when the recursion is over, but somehow the function `doit` is returning `None` here. Though printing `x` within the def prints the correct string.
What am I doing wrong?

```
strs = "i am a string but i've some {text in brackets} braces, and here are some more {i am the second one} braces"
def doit(x,ind=0):
   if x.find('{',ind)!=-1 and x.find('}',ind)!=-1:
     start=x.find('{',ind)
     end=x.find('}',ind)
     y=x[start:end+1]
     x=x[:start]+x[end+1:]
     #print(x)
     doit(x,end+1)
   else:
       return x

print(doit(strs))
```

**output:**
`None`

Comment: I'd note this is a really bad way of doing it, but I'm presuming this is a programming exercise, given the "I'm trying to do it recursively" statement.

Comment: @Lattyware yeah! I was trying to solve a SO problem through this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never return anything if the `if` block succeeds. The `return` statement lies in the `else` block, and is only executed if everything else isn't. You want to return the value you get from the recursion.

```
if x.find('{', ind) != -1 and x.find('}', ind) != -1:
    ...
    return doit(x, end+1)
else:
    return x
```

Comment: To add, when function ends without the explicit `return` or with explicit `return` that is given no argument, then it is the same as if you used `return None`.

Answer (score 1):

```
...
#print(x)
doit(x,end+1)
...
```

should be

```
...
#print(x)
return doit(x,end+1)
...
```

You are missing the `return` statement in the if block. If the function is calls itself recursively, it doesn't return the return value of that call.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is easier to use regular expressions:

```
import re
strs = "i am a string but i've some {text in brackets} braces, and here are some more {i am the second one} braces"
strs = re.sub(r'{.*?}', '', strs)
```

Comment: I know that it can be done in one line, I was just trying somewhat different(recursive) approach than using`regex`.