# Function always returns None

Tags: python, return

I have some Python code that basically looks like this:

```
my_start_list = ...

def process ( my_list ):
    #do some stuff
    
    if len(my_list) > 1:
        process(my_list)
    else:
        print(my_list)
        return my_list
   
print(process(my_start_list))
```

The strange thing is: `print(my_list)` prints out the correct content. However, the second print statement printing the return value of the function always prints `None`.
Even if I replace the normal `return` statement with `return("abc")` it is still `None`.

As the content of the variable seems to be correct one line before the return statement, I don't know where to start debugging.
Are there any common problems that may cause this?

Comment: use `return process(my_list)` when calling it recursively.

Comment: @NPE I'm assuming `#do some stuff` includes modifying the list in some way; otherwise you're right; this should recurse indefinitely.

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097822/weird-function-return-value

Comment: The do some stuff does indeed modify the list, so indefinite recursion should not occur.
But the missing return was indeed the problem, I didn't know it had to be done that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's what happening:

1. You call `process(my_start_list)`.
2. In the function, the `if` block is executed if `len(my_list) > 1`, and there are no return statement there. Now, since the `else` has not been executed and since that is the only place where you have the return clause, you return the default which is `None`.
3. If you have 0 or 1 elements in your list, you return that list.

To fix this, you'd want to return the list returned by `process(my_list)`.

That is:

```
def process(my_list):
    # do some stuff
    ...
    if len(my_list) > 1:
        return process(my_list)
    else:
        print(my_list)
        return my_list
```

Answer (score 9):

You're only returning the list when you have 1 or 0 elements in it (the base case). You need a return statement in the first block as well, where you make the recursive call, or else you drill down to the base case, return the length-1 list to the next level, and then return `None` the rest of the way up. So what you want looks like this, instead:

```
def process(my_list):
    # Do some stuff.
    if len(my_list) > 1:
        return process(my_list) #If you don't return this result, you return None
    else:
        print(my_list)
        return my_list
```

Now *every* case (not just the base case) has a return value, so that return value will propagate all the way back up to your initial call.

Comment: His function is recursive; he's going to end up with at least two return statements no matter what he does (one for the base case and one for the recursive call).

Comment: @marksweb: **Why** would a single return better? This has been discussed to death, but that is no longer true. See [Should a function have only one return statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36707)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm open to being wrong given my experience, but it's what I've always been told & how I work to make keeping track of things easier. I'll give that post a read!

Answer (score 3):

You call `process` recursively but never ignore it's return value when you do. Add a `return` statement to *pass on* the return value::

```
def process ( my_list ):
    #do some stuff

    if len(my_list) > 1:
        return process(my_list)
    else:
        print(my_list)
        return my_list
```

Now, when `len(my_list) > 1` is `True`, you actually pass on the return value of the recursive call.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you are missing a `return` statement.

I personally would turn that tail recursion into iteration:

```
def process(my_list):
    while True:
        # do some stuff
        if len(my_list) <= 1:
            return my_list
```

I think this makes the intent a little clearer, and also avoids some [pitfalls associated with tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591970/does-python-optimize-tail-recursion).