# recursion None python

Tags: python, recursion, elementtree

This is an XML parser code snippet which returns with None value. This is a large XML file  that has a lot of subfields like this:

```xml
<root>
    <field name ="1">
        <field name ="2" showname ="ZZZ">
            <field name ="3" showname="YYY">
                <field name ="4" showname="XXX"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </field>
```

The `findall()` finds all the elements with a tag which are direct children of the current element. I tried this, but it returned with None. It prints nothing also.

```
def findXXX(field):
    if field.get('name') == 'XXX' :
        return field.get('showname')
    else:
        for fieldchild in field.findall('field'):
            return findXXX(fieldchild)
```

If I write like this, it prints the correct value, however it returns with None.

```
def findXXX(field):
    if field.get('name') == 'XXX' :
        print field.get('showname')
        return field.get('showname')
    else:
        for fieldchild in field.findall('field'):
            findXXX(fieldchild)
```

Comment: In your first code block, I suspect having an unconditional `return` inside a `for` loop is a logic error; it will only iterate once before terminating.

Comment: Your recursion only explores the leftmost branch of the tree because you `return` immediately in your `for` loop.  Either accumulate in a list and return at the end of your loop or rewrite it into a generator.

Comment: BTW, do you mean to test for the `'name'` attribute or the `'showname'` attribute? You are testing against `'XXX'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second version, you are *ignoring* the return value of the recursive call. Your first version at least still returned that return value:

```
for fieldchild in field.findall('field'):
    return findXXX(fieldchild)
```

The `return` statement in your function returns to the *direct caller*, not to the caller of the outermost first invocation of `findXXX()`.

However now only the result for the *first* `field` in the `field.findall()` list will return something. You probably want to return the first that is *not `None`*:

```
for fieldchild in field.findall('field'):
    result = findXXX(fieldchild)
    if result is not None:
        return result
```

This kicks of a recursive search for each `field` element, and returns the result of the *first* such recursive calls that is not `None`.

Note that you don't *have* to recurse; you can also use an [XPath expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) to search through the tree without having to recurse yourself:

```
field.find(".//field[@showname='XXX']")
```

This returns the first `field` tag whose `name` attribute is set to `XXX`, *searching recursively*.

Demo:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.fromstring('''\
... <root>
...     <field name ="1">
...         <field name ="2" showname ="ZZZ">
...             <field name ="3" showname="YYY">
...                 <field name ="4" showname="XXX"/>
...             </field>
...         </field>
...     </field>
... </root>
... ''')
>>> tree.find(".//field[@showname='XXX']")
<Element 'field' at 0x108519bd0>
>>> tree.find(".//field[@showname='XXX']").get('name')
'4'
```

Comment: @user3816048: no, my answer is not exactly what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you use BeautifulSoup. It is easy to learn, has good documentation. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

A soup object can be instantiated using the code below, where "markup" is a string containing your XML, or input file handle to the XML file:

```
BeautifulSoup(markup, "xml")
```

Comment: The issue is how to handle a recursion here. As it stands, this is more of a comment.

Comment: My point why write XML parsing code when a well-tested module already does it.

Comment: ElementTree and BeautifulSoup are two different approaches to providing the user with a *tree model*.

Comment: But note that BeautifulSoup is better suited for HTML, really. The XML support is lovely, but still has some bugs and spotty coverage for more.. esoteric elements of the XML standard, such as processing instructions.