# python recursion dir return NONE

Tags: python, recursion

1.recursion filesList in dir，if found the file then return the file path

2.print value is true. but always return NONE

```
def getFilePath(filepath,fileName):
    files = os.listdir(filepath)
    for fi in files:
        fi_d = os.path.join(filepath, fi)
        if os.path.isdir(fi_d):
            getFilePath(fi_d, fileName)
        else :
            if fi_d.find(fileName) == -1:
                continue
            else:
                print fi_d
                return fi_d
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should return at the end of the function only, otherwise python returns None

Also, need to capture the recursive return

```
def getFilePath(filepath,fileName):

    for fi in os.listdir(filepath):
        fi_d = os.path.join(filepath, fi)
        if os.path.isdir(fi_d):
            fi_d = getFilePath(fi_d, fileName)
        else :
            if fi_d.find(fileName) == -1:
                continue
            else:
                print fi_d
    return fi_d
```

Comment: To be clearer: your recursive chain's final return can only be None.  Only 1 call is going to hit your value return.  The stack will then propagate None returns through to the end since the remaining calls will simple reach the end and return the default None.

Comment: use cricket_007 way, the function have return, but return value don't hit my value

Comment: Not sure what that means, but your function should no longer return None, which at least addresses that part of your question. I don't know what your function's expected output actually is