# Why does this search function return no value?

Tags: python

My son is teaching himself Python, but has stumped me with the following. Why does the Search function on this class return `None`?

We are obviously hitting the `return` as without it the function recurses indefinitely, and on the line above the value of `self.found` printed is correct.

```
class Search:
    def __init__(self):
        print("made")
        self.n = 0
        self.found = []
    def search(self, Object, List):
        if self.n == 0:
            self.found.clear()
            print("1:self.found =", self.found, "\nself.n =", self.n)
        if len(List) == self.n:
            self.n = 0
            print("2:self.found =", self.found, "\nself.n =", self.n)
            return self.found
        if List[self.n] == Object:
            self.found.append(self.n)
            print("3:self.found =", self.found, "\nself.n =", self.n)
            self.n = self.n + 1
            print("4:self.found =", self.found, "\nself.n =", self.n)
            self.search(Object, List)
        else:
            self.n = self.n + 1
            print("5:self.found =", self.found, "\nself.n =", self.n)
            self.search(Object, List)
```

Comment: When you call yourself recurively, you have to return the result of the recurive call all the way up.

Comment: If you want a function to return something, all of its possible code paths should have a `return` statement, not just one of them. This is true even for recursive functions. Related reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-function-return-none

Comment: could you provide an example list that you are using?

Comment: @Kevin all branches either recurse or return, he got that far (although the layout of the function is a little... unorthodox, I'll give you)

Comment: With recursive functions, pretend you're calling *some other function*, even when calling the same function recursively, or mentally replace the recursive call with `# and then magic happens`, to remove any confusion. *Are* you hitting the `return` statement on the first, direct call to `search`? Probably not.

Comment: @mavnn: but the recursive function calls are still *just function calls*. If you called anything other than a recursive function, would you also just ignore the value that call returned?

Comment: @JohanL - okay, got you. Been writing in a language with implicit returns for a while and failed to spot what you meant for a moment.