# Function Returning None When Recursion Employed

Tags: python

I'm sure I'm making a simple error but in my function looking to return the factorial of a user given input when the input isn't 1 or 0 it actually just returns none. I printed out what it was doing within the helper function and it looks like it obtained the proper result but when I run it as below it returns none. Please let me know what obvious oversight I'm making. Thanks.

```
def recurseFactorial(num, mySum):
    if num==0 or num==1:
        return mySum
    else:
        recurseFactorial(num-1,mySum=mySum*num)

while True:
    myInput = input("Please enter the number: ")
    print(recurseFactorial(int(myInput), 1))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `else` branch, you're *calling* recurseFactorial, but you're not *returning* its result.  And since that branch has no `return` statement, it returns `None` by default.

You want this instead:

```
def recurseFactorial(num, mySum):
    if num==0 or num==1:
        return mySum
    else:
        return recurseFactorial(num-1,mySum=mySum*num)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much. Knew I was missing something easy. Appreciate it.