# function returns none instead of a tuple

Tags: python, tuples, nonetype

I am using python 2.7. I wrote a code to generate passwords. For doing this, I used the random module to generate how many characters of different types(uppercase, lowercase, special and numbers) to be used to generate a password of a given length. When a wrote a function for this, it was supposed to return a tuple, but it returns None. Why is it happening?

I tried the casual debugging method of putting print statements in between and figuring out where it went wrong. Everything works just fine, except it returns None.

```py
def passlen(a):
    """Gives length of different characters to be put into passwords"""
    uplen=random.randrange(0, a)
    lwlen=random.randrange(0, a)
    speclen=random.randrange(0, a)
    nmbrlen=random.randrange(0, a)
    if uplen+lwlen+speclen+nmbrlen==a:
        print (uplen, lwlen, speclen, nmbrlen)
        return(uplen, lwlen, speclen, nmbrlen)
    else:
        passlen(a)

x=input("how many characters in the password?")

print(passlen(x))
```

Expected results are 4-tuples, but it gives None instead.

Comment: where is Your `return` statement? o_0

Comment: right above the `else` statement

Comment: So... most of the time it's not being executed, wherefore the function returns `None`.

Comment: But isn't a function only supposed to return at the end of a `return` statement? And it returns `None` if no `return` statement is found.

Comment: So, most of the time Your function does not reach the end statement. Only if the sum is equal to `a`. You have None when the function exits without explicit return statement. It's sounds better then just guessing what did You actually wanted to return.

Comment: My apologies. I do not understand what you are saying. I am using recursion here . And as I see in most recursive functions, the results work just fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Kamiccolo for trying to help out.

The function should look like this:

```
def passlen(a):
    """Gives length of different characters to be put into passwords"""
    uplen=int(random.randrange(0, a))
    lwlen=int(random.randrange(0, a))
    speclen=int(random.randrange(0, a))
    nmbrlen=int(random.randrange(0, a))
    bab=(uplen, lwlen, speclen, nmbrlen)
    if uplen+lwlen+speclen+nmbrlen==a:
        return bab
    else:
        return passlen(a)
```

A [duplicate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-python-function-return-none) also helped me in this.

Comment: This is problematic. You can expect a StackOverflowError with this code for large enough values of `a` because instead of simply looping until you get a suitable result, you keep calling the same function recursively. And you don't actually need a loop at all.

Comment: This is the best answer to the question of *why* the "function returns none instead of a tuple".  The recursion depth of python is defaulted at 1,000... so fingers crossed that the random numbers give the desired results, but, this is the answer to the question asked w/o regard to code quality.

Answer (score 1):

So you want four random numbers that add to `a`? Of course you can try choosing four random numbers until you find a set that adds up to `a`, but that might take a while for large values of `a` (and you definitely don't want to do this recursively).

Much better to choose three split points between `0` and `a`:

```
def passlen(a):
    splits = sorted([random.randrange(0,a) for _ in range(3)])
    uplen = splits[0]
    lwlen = splits[1] - uplen
    speclen = splits[2] - uplen - lwlen
    nmbrlen = a - uplen - lwlen - speclen
    return uplen, lwlen, speclen, nmbrlen
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

def passlen(a):
    """Gives length of different characters to be put into passwords"""
    uplen = random.randrange(0, a)
    lwlen = random.randrange(0, a)
    speclen = random.randrange(0, a)
    nmbrlen = random.randrange(0, a)
    if uplen + lwlen + speclen + nmbrlen == a:
        print("Length of Uppercase:", uplen)
        print("Length of Lowercase:", lwlen)
        print("Length of Special characters:", speclen)
        print("Length of Numeric characters:", nmbrlen)
        return (uplen, lwlen, speclen, nmbrlen)
    else:
        return passlen(a)

x = int(input("How many characters in the password? "))  # Convert input to integer

print("Generated Password Lengths:", passlen(x))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).