# Why doesn't the return statement terminate the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, return

```
def gcd_fast(a, b):
    if(b > a):
        a, b = b, a


    if(a % b == 0):
        return b
    else:
        rem = a % b
        print('C:' + str(rem))
        gcd_fast(b, rem)    
print(gcd_fast(10, 9))
```

It returns none and when runnig it with the debugger after the return statement it jumps back to   `gcd_fast(a, b)` in the if clause. I'm not good with python at all so sorry if it's something silly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? (ffs auto comment, i *know* it answers the question, why would i suggest it otherwise) [Why does my recursive python function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-python-function-return-none)

Comment: you didn't return in the recursive call.

Comment: `return gcd_fast(b, rem)`?

Comment: The else block returns None

Answer (score 0):

```
def gcd_fast(a, b):
    if(b > a):
        a, b = b, a


    if(a % b == 0):
        return b
    else:
        rem = a % b
        print('C:' + str(rem))
        return gcd_fast(b, rem)
```