# Python: Why variable is treated as a 'NoneType' despite having been defined as an integer?

Tags: python, recursion, return, typeerror

I am making a simple script in Python as an exercise that evaluates the [Ackermann Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function). First the script asks the user for an input, and then attempts to calculate the rest. Here is the code:

```
m = int(input('Please input m.\n'))
n = int(input('Please input n.\n'))


def compute(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        print(n + 1)
    elif m > 0 and n == 0:
        compute(m - 1, 1)
    else:
        compute(m - 1, compute(m, n - 1))


compute(m, n)
```

The part that has me confused is when it returns a **TypeError**, particularly for **lines in compute(m, n) where I attempt to add or subtract 1 from n and m.**

```
print(n + 1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I understand that Python takes all inputs as string, which is why I specifically converted the input
using int() at the very start of the script. And yet, **the TypeError seems to implicate that in compute(m, n), m and n are not int, but rather NoneType thus they cannot be added or subtracted. Why is this, and how can I fix this?**

Comment: `compute` is recursive, but doesn't explicitly return, meaning that `None` is always returned.

Comment: Your function isn't returning a result.  All it does is print `n+1` if `m` is zero.  None of the recursive calls will work.

Comment: Python by default returns ```None``` . Recursion must have at least one stopping condition. Else, it will result to stackoverlow.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I understand now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any [fruitful](https://www.pythonlearn.com/html-008/cfbook005.html#toc51) recursive function must have one or more return statements. Refer [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/201765/46808).

```
m = int(input('Please input m.\n'))
n = int(input('Please input n.\n'))

def compute(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        return n + 1
    elif m > 0 and n == 0:
        return compute(m - 1, 1)
    else:
        return compute(m - 1, compute(m, n - 1))


print(compute(m, n))
```

should work as you expect.

Comment: It would be better to explain what you actually changed and why it solves the problem instead of just putting a piece of code