# A empty list becomes None

Tags: python

[my code and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsoeX.png)
[the tutorial code and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FB33.png)

This is my code

```
def delete_starting_evens(lst):
    for x in lst:
        if x%2 == 0:
            lst = lst[1:]
        else:
            return lst

print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15]))
print(delete_starting_evens([4, 8, 10]))
```

I get:

```
[11, 12, 15]
None
```

I was expecting to get:

```
[11, 12, 15]
[]
```

Can someone explain this?

Picture one is my trial. Picture two is the standard answer. I try to get an empty list by using my for loop. However, it seems that the [] still satisfy the condition of my for loop and somehow make the [] become a None object. Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Give a [mre] **as text** in the question

Comment: What does `None` have to do with the question? The assignment doesn't ask for `None` and you don't return `None`. Why mention `None` at all?

Comment: Ah, I missed the first image. So, if you don't return while you're in the loop, the function returns after the loop, and returns `None` as you don't specify anything to return.

Comment: I was expecting to get a [], but it returns None. That's what I am asking. I am surprised the [] didn't break the for loop and return itself.

Comment: How dose an empty list [] still satisfy the condition:                                                              
    for x in last:
        if x%2 == 0:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 2):

If all items in the list satisfies the condition `x % 2 == 0`, the return statement will not be executed, and the function will return the default value of `None`.

Possible solution: Replace `return lst` with `break`, and place `return lst` at the end of the function.

Comment: Thanks. I got it.