# Return function in recursion

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search

Understanding the use of `return` statement in `recursion`

For example in Binary Search:

```
def binary_search_recur(array,start,end,item):

    middle = int((start+end)/2)
    #print (middle)
    if (start>end):
        return -1
    else:   
        if array[middle]==item:
            return middle
        elif array[middle]>item:
            return binary_search_recur(array,start,middle-1,item)
        else:
            return binary_search_recur(array,middle+1,end,item)
```

Calling the function with

```
array = [27,45,76,81,92,101,291]
binary_search_recur(array,0,len(array)-1,27)
```

Works fine if I add `return` statement everywhere, but it does not return `0` (the index of the searched element in the example) if I remove the `return` statement like below

```
else:   
      if array[middle]==item:
           return middle
      elif array[middle]>item:
           binary_search_recur(array,start,middle-1,item) #retrun statement removed
      else:
           binary_search_recur(array,middle+1,end,item)   #retrun statement removed
```

My point is, i would want to return when I find the element so I return the index `middle`, or if the element is not present at all so in that case I return `-1`, otherwise I am just calling the function recursively with updated `start` and `end` index, Just like merge sort

```
merge_sort(l)
merge_sort(r)
merge(l,r,array)
```

So I dont understand why removing the `return` statement like in the example does not return the op. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: You're calling the function whether you return its result or not. If you don't return the result,  that invocation of the function will return `None` when it exits the `if` block.

Comment: Your *first* invocation of the function will recursively call itself but never return the result. So, without return you'd get a call chain `fn` (first time) -> `fn` (second time) but the result of `fn()` (second time) is just ignored. No different to just calling a non-recursive function that doesn't do a `return`. Or more properly having something like `if True: return 1 else: 1;` and expecting a return value for `fn(False)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Comment: To be clear: you don't understand why an expression that doesn't start with `return` is not returned?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, my confusion is I am calling the recursion with updated start and end so there is noting to return unless I find the element or if the element is not present at all.

Comment: @vikky Did my example below help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There's nothing special to recursion** - it's just plain functions calls and the fact that the function is calling itself is actually totally irrelevant -, and `return` works just the same as everywhere else.

Consider this:

```
def a(arg):
    return arg +1 

def b(arg):
    return a(arg * 2)

def main():
    result = b(42)
    print(result)
```

If you remove the `return` in `b` ie:

```
def b(arg):
    a(arg * 2)
```

then technically what you actually wrote is:

```
def b(arg):
    a(arg * 2)
    return None
```

since when they end up without an explicit `return` statement, Python functions implicitely return `None`. And  as a result, in `main()`, `result` will be `None` instead of `(arg * 2) + 1`

It's the **exact** same thing happening in your code - if you don't explicitely return the result of the recursive call (=> once again, the fact it's a recursive call is technically totally irrelevant, it works *exactly* the same way), your function will return `None`, just has if you wrote:

```
    elif array[middle]>item:
        binary_search_recur(array,start,middle-1,item)
        return None
    else:
        binary_search_recur(array,middle+1,end,item)
        return None
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, I understand this now. But if we consider this , I am confused on how does merge sort work without the ```return``` statement. So the presence of return statement is decided upon mutation of the array, variable passed in the function?

Comment: This is still the same as with just any other function - either your function works by returning a new object (in which case you need the return statements obviously) or by mutating it's argument(s) in place - in which case there's no need to return anything, and the convention in this case is indeed to return `None` (cf all the builtin type methods that mutate the current instance in place is `list.sort()` etc).  IOW you either return a new value OR (exclusive OR) mutate your argument in place. And once again, just consider the recursive call as a plain ordinary call - that's what it is

Answer (score 1):

Idea of recurring function is that it returns new execution of itself with new parameters or final value.

You need to **return** result of next method in recurring loop. If not, Python returns None and result of your inner recurring functions aren't saved anywhere.

Comment: But it works fine for merge sort without the return statement, so I dont understand the difference?

Comment: @vikky is merge sorting mutating its input in-place?

Comment: @vikky Because merge sort modifies the given list inplace and there is no return value.

Comment: @glglgl my understanding is merge sort is not a in-place sorting algorithm since it creates copy of the recursed arrays unlike quick sort.

Comment: @VLAZ no it does not mutate in place, it creates copies. So the requirement of return statement falls to modification of in-place array, variable etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the following input

```
array = [0,1,2,3,4]
item = 1
```

Your function takes the following steps

1. `start = 0`, `end = 4`, `middle = 2`.

In this case in your function body, you enter the part with `elif array[middle]>item`. Then your recursive function calls a second recursive function with the following input

2. `start = 0`, `end = 1`, `middle = 0`.

In this case you enter the very last `else` block. Then you call a third function with the following input

3. `start = 1`, `end = 1`, `middle = 1`.

Now the magic begins. You function finds `middle`, and returns `1`. This takes you back to the line with your 2nd recursive function. Your 2nd recursive function returns `1` and it takes you back to your 1st recursive function, and finally it returns `1` too.

If you delete those returns. In this example, step 1 and 2 return nothing, in other words `None`.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you have to "return the returned value".

for example when the following condition passes:

`array[middle]>item`

your method is not returning anything. so python will return None instead.