# Python function return problem, it returns None

Tags: python, function, math, return

i want to calculate sum of every digit. For example, if we have number 134,we calculate 1+3+4 =8 and print it out. I did this in c, it works fine but when i try it in python it doesn't work. Here is my code: [python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRoNr.jpg)

Comment: Please include the code in your question itself. Do not paste pictures of your code. See [how to ask ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I dont have internet connection on my pc at the moment. Im writing from my phone

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 1):

the problem in your code is that it has no `return` statement; by default, Python will return `None`.

That being said, I would recommend you to add the code to the question in the next questions; just as skrrrt commented :).

Comment: U r right, i should have added the code but as i mentioned i dont have net connection on my pc at the moment. Hot can i resolve the problem, i wanna return the top value

Comment: Try changing the call to "get(sayi, top)" for "return get(sayi, top)" in line 49.