# Finding index in nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, nested-lists

I am trying to create a function that will take as input a nested list and an item, and return a list of indices.
For example `list  = [0, 5, [6, 8, [7, 3, 6]], 9, 10]` and  `item = 7` should return `[2, 2, 0]`, since `list[2][2][0] = 7`

my code should work since I can print the desires output, but when i run it it returns None.

```
def find_item(list_input, item, current):
    if list_input == item:
        print(current) ## this does give the desires output, but the function should return not print
        return current
    else:
        if isinstance(list_input, list):
            for j in range(len(list_input)):
                current.append(j)
                find_item(list_input[j], item, current)
                del current[-1]
```

what am I overlooking here?

Comment: You need to handle the return value from the recursive `find_item` call as well.

Comment: Well, first of all you're not returning anything in your else:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @tzaman mentioned, you need to handle the return value of `find_item` recursive call. If the return value of the recursive call is a list, it will mean that searched item is found and we need to stop the recursion.

The following modification will return the earliest found index of the searched item. If no item is found, it will return `None`.

```
def find_item(list_input, item, current):
    if list_input == item:
        return current
    else:
        if isinstance(list_input, list):
            for j in range(len(list_input)):
                current.append(j)
                search_result = find_item(list_input[j], item, current)
                if isinstance(search_result, list):
                    return search_result
                del current[-1]

list_input  = [0, 5, [6, 8, [7, 3, 6]], 9, 10]
item = 7
print(find_item(list_input, item, []))

list_input  = [0, 5, [6, 8, [7, 3, 6]], 9, 10]
item = 9
print(find_item(list_input, item, []))

list_input  = [0, 5, [6, 8, [7, 3, 6]], [30, 4], 9, 10]
item = 4
print(find_item(list_input, item, []))

list_input  = [0, 5, [6, 8, [7, 3, 6]], [30, 4], 9, 10]
item = 400
print(find_item(list_input, item, []))
```

Output:

```
[2, 2, 0]
[3]
[3, 1]
None
```

Answer (score 0):

It always bothers me when someone sticks a `for` loop in the middle of a *recursive* function!  Here's a different way to go about this problem:

```
def find_item(list_input, item, index=0):
    if list_input:
        head, *tail = list_input

        if head == item:
            return [index]

        if isinstance(head, list):
            if result := find_item(head, item):
                return [index] + result

        return find_item(tail, item, index + 1)
    
    return list_input

list_input  = [0, 5, [6, 8, [7, 3, 1]], 9, 10]

print(find_item(list_input, 7))
```

This solution doesn't require an *explicit* third argument.  And returns an empty `list` upon failure to find the item, rather than `None`.  Note the use of the new *walrus* operator **:=**

```
            if result := find_item(head, item):
```

If that's a problem, instead do:

```
            result = find_item(head, item)
            if result:
```