# (Python) Binary tree search algorithm

Tags: python

Here is problem: when I write any number to find, it says, that it was found, but index is `None`. What can I do?

```
tree = [1, 3, 5, 8, 12, 14, 17, 21, 25, 28, 29, 31, 35, 40, 45, 48, 50]

input = int(input())

def binnary_tree_search(list, wanted_number, start, stop):
    if start > stop: return False
    middle = (start + stop) // 2
    if wanted_number < list[middle]:
        binnary_tree_search(list, wanted_number, start, middle - 1)
    elif wanted_number > list[middle]:
        binnary_tree_search(list, wanted_number, middle + 1, stop)
    else:
        return middle
        
result = binnary_tree_search(tree, input, 0, len(tree))

if result == False:
    print("The number was not found")
else:
    print(str(input) + " was found with index " + str(result))
```

Comment: You may want to avoid using built-in names such as `input` and `list` as variable names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return the value of the recursive call:

```
def binnary_tree_search(list, wanted_number, start, stop):
    if start > stop: return False
    middle = (start + stop) // 2
    if wanted_number < list[middle]:
        return binnary_tree_search(list, wanted_number, start, middle - 1)
    elif wanted_number > list[middle]:
        return binnary_tree_search(list, wanted_number, middle + 1, stop)
    else:
        return middle
```

Comment: @Endivine https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers