# Method returns 'NoneType' object

Tags: python, object, nonetype

So the method looks like this:

```
def find_node(self, sym, root):
    if root.symbol == sym:
        print(root.__str__())
        print(isinstance(root, Node))
        return root
    if root.l is not None:
        self.find_node(sym, root.l)
    if root.r is not None:
        self.find_node(sym, root.r)
```

After some recursive calls, it finds the node we're looking for and returns it. Before return, the check isinstance() returns True, so its not a NoneType object.

Now, the method which takes the result is:

```
def code_path(c_tree, sym):
    node = c_tree.find_node(sym, c_tree.get_root())
    print(isinstance(node, Node))
```

and the isinstance method returns false - the node instance is NoneType.

I cannot figure out how a NoneType object gets returned, when the object to be returned by the previous method is one of the proper type. Any ideas?

Comment: All of your code paths should `return` something, not just the first `if`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_node(self, sym, root):
    if root.symbol == sym:
        print(root.__str__())
        print(isinstance(root, Node))
        return root
    elif root.l is not None:
        return self.find_node(sym, root.l)
    elif root.r is not None:
        return self.find_node(sym, root.r)
```

You also need to return your recursive calls.

Comment: This seems right, but it doesn't work as intended now. The goal of the method is to return the node of a binary tree which has node.symbol = sym. With my initial implementation, it would find this node after some calls but it wouldn't return it. Now, it finds a node with node.symbol != sym and returns a NoneType again. I'm confused.

Comment: The logic of the code isn't changed, it behaves the same way. I'll need some debugging details, what's the output of `print(node)` in `code_path`?

Comment: The output is None.

Comment: Also are self and root istances of the same Node class?

Comment: No, self is the Tree class

Answer (score 0):

If the first if condition passes, the function dosent return anything, so it returns None.

Here is what you should do (if I understand what you wanted to do):

```python
def find_node(self, sym, root):
    if root.symbol == sym:
        print(root.__str__())
        print(isinstance(root, Node))
        return root
    if root.l is not None:
        return self.find_node(sym, root.l)
    if root.r is not None:
        return self.find_node(sym, root.r)
```