# Why does the function return None in a recursive count of random numbers?

Tags: python, recursion

For educational purposes of understanding recursion I would like to solve the following problem: given a list of integers `foo` in which `0` is guaranteed, I would like to choose a number from that list randomly until either the random generator chooses `0` or until it works `100` times.

Iteratively speaking, my solution looks like this:

```
def num_random(foo):
    nums = 0
    x = math.inf
    while nums < 100 and x != 0:
        x = random.choice(foo)
        nums += 1
    return nums
```

My recursive version of the same function is this:

```
def count_random(foo, number):
    x = random.choice(foo)
    print("x = {0}".format(x)) # debug purposes
    if x != 0 and number < 100:
        count_random(foo, number + 1)
    else:
        return number
```

Initial call:

```
print(count_random([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0))
```

The problem with the recursive solution is that it always returns `None` and I don't understand why. My reasoning: if the chosen number is not `0`, we know that the number of integers in the next call will be the number of integers in the current call plus 1. If the randomly chosen integer is `0`, we need to return the number of integers in the outer scope. However, my function always returns `None`.

Why does my function always return `None` and how do I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `return` statement in your recursive call:

```
def count_random(foo, number):
    x = random.choice(foo)
    print("x = {0}".format(x)) # debug purposes
    if x != 0 and number < 100:
        return count_random(foo, number + 1)
    else:
        return number
```