# Unable to understand 'None' output of recursive calls

Tags: python, recursion, return

Have an unusual request regarding code implementation at [ideone](https://ideone.com/iVI6mE):

```
n = 42
new= []
m = 0

def convert(n,m):
    print "round #:", m,"n :", n
    a = ((n+1) % 3)-1
    if n:
        new.append(a); print 'new :', new
        print 'call convert(' (n+1)//3,',',m+1,'):',convert((n+1)//3,m+1)
        print 'after convert(' , n, ',' ,m,  ')','\n'
    else:
        print 'n==',n, 'new: ::: ', new,'\n\n',
        return new, n

print  convert(n,m), "<<---- None returned ? "
```

I don't know why 'None' is printed in the output below. The output 'None' is printed in two places (cases):

Case #1. print 'after convert(' , n, ',' ,m,  ')','\n'

Case #2. print  convert(n,m), "<<---- None returned ? "

I am not at all clear why if the default case of 'n=0' has proper value of list 'new', then how is it that in case #2, 'None' is returned.

According to me, 'new' contents should be printed in case #2.

---

Even more confusing is: why case #1 is returning 'None' each time for non-zero value of 'n'?

According to me, there should be no 'None' printed for case #1.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid None from being your output, we have to ensure that your function returns a value.

In your case, there is a return statement in the `else` statement but not the `if` statement.

You might either introduce a return statement for the `if` part or change the indentation for the function return statement.

```
n = 42
new= []
m = 0

def convert(n,m):
    print "round #:", m,"n :", n
    a = ((n+1) % 3)-1
    if n:
        new.append(a); print 'new :', new
        print 'call convert(' +  str((n+1)//3,) + ',',m+1,'):',convert((n+1)//3,m+1)
        print 'after convert(' , n, ',' ,m,  ')','\n'
    else:
        print 'n==',n, 'new: ::: ', new,'\n\n',
    return new, n

print  convert(n,m)
```

Comment: I think you are stating for Case #2, i.e. for printing contents of list 'new'. But the unasked for 'None' in case #1 is confusing a lot.

Comment: Each time you call convert without a return, you get a None.

Comment: btw, you are encouraged to change to Python 3.

Comment: I am good at understanding and coding basic python code. But, got via a mse post (comment by : djangofan 
to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/695979/424260) code in java at: https://repl.it/@djangofan/RecusiveTaskFibonaccijava. Request to know if forking is needed in it or not. If yes, why a normal (sequential) code wouldn't work.

Comment: what are you trying to do?  the author seems to want a recursive implementation.

Comment: Thanks. If just recursive implementation is needed, then why fork is used on line #25, and not just sequential implementation?

Comment: Please elaborate on my last comment.

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork–join_model) is more reading on fork-join model. mainly parallel computing.

Comment: Request what the code is doing (by forking out each time), or even better (sorry, but couldn't help) have it in python. Also, is it needed? For Fibonacci series computation, answer at: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/238733/327853 , states it is a bad choice.

Comment: if you have a new specific question, ask it as a post, avoid long comment threads.

Comment: Lack courage, had it been mse would had. If agree, can open chat.
You can help otherwise by making a new post.