# why this recursive function return None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here my codes:

```
v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]

def con(v, i):
    if i == len(v) : return print("ok")
    con(v, i + 1)

print(con(v, 1))
```

heres the output:

```
ok
None
```

Does anyone know how i can solve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none

Answer (score 2):

1. `print` returns `None` and you are returning `print`s result
2. you forgot to return on line 5, it should be `return con(v, i + 1)` or else the function will return `None`

Comment: Oh, ops, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Your code prints that because the result of this code is `print(print("ok"))` and  a call to print returns `None`. You need to return something other than `print("ok")`.

Comment: even if I remove the print the result doesn't change

Comment: that's because you need to return something other than `print("ok")`, like the results of the recursion. szdytom's answer addresses what you want probably.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `con(v,1)`.
No need to use `print(con(v,1))`

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question that you want to recursively obtain the length of the vector / go to the end of the vector. You need to get the result from the inner most recursion loop back to the outer most. Thus you need to return the result of the inner ones:

```
v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
def con(v, i):
    if i == len(v):
        print("ok")
        return i
    return(con(v, i + 1))

print("Length of vector is: ",con(v, 1))
```

that will give:

```
ok
Length of vector is:  6
```