# Recursive function variable scope confusion in Python

Tags: python, variables, recursion, scope, local

```
def my_function():
    try:
        number = int(input("What is your favorite number?\n\n"))
    except ValueError: #if anything but an integer was given as the str to input
        my_function() #recursive to ask again
    return number
my_function()
```

This throws the exception `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number' referenced before assignment` if I go through the recursive scope at least once and then give a valid input. I thought the variable number should point to a different object every iteration of the function. What am I missing here?

I recognize I can simply move `return number` into the `try` block to achieve this functionality, but why do I have to?

Comment: Use `return my_function()` in the exception clause and things may work better. With that in mind, (re)read Karl's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought the variable number should point to a different object every iteration of the function.

What causes the local variable `number` to get set in the current call? Answer: `number = int(input("What is your favorite number?\n\n"))`. Does it always get assigned? Answer: No, not if `int` raises an exception. When does the recursive call happen? Answer: when, and only when, the exception is raised. Therefore, when a recursive call happens, does `number` have a value set in the current call? Answer: **No**.

> I recognize I can simply move return number into the try block to achieve this functionality

No; this *does not work*! If the exception is raised, then `return number` does not happen in the current call. The recursive call will occur, and then the value returned from that recursive call will *be ignored*. In the current call, control flow reaches the end of the function, and `None` is returned. You would have to [explicitly `return` the value from the recursive call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none), or explicitly assign it to `number` and then `return` that afterward.

But that's ugly. You should *just use a loop for this*, [like everyone else does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Comment: Great explanation for something quite counterintuitive to me. Thank you!

Comment: The golden rule for understanding recursion: imagine the recursive call is to a *different* function that somehow magically does what you want the recursive call to do (complete black box), and then consider the logic normally.

Comment: Yeah that;s exactly where my understanding was lacking. Before I thought a recursive call is an extension of one function, not a new "nested" function call. I see it properly now, thank you!

Comment: Yep. Again, it's the same as a non-recursive call, except for the recursiveness. ;)