# Python: Weird results from recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I wanted to write a recursive function to fit curves. For some reasons my results didn't looked good so I boiled down the problem to one easy example:

```
Number = 6
Successor = 0

def Fuction(Number, Successor):
    if (Number - Successor)+1>0:
       Successor += 1
       Fuction(Number, Successor)
    else:
        return(Fuction(Number, Successor))

A = Fuction(Number, Successor) 
print(f'The Successor of {Number} is {A}')
```

When I do this I get the output

```
7
The Successor of 6 is 1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why `print(Successor)` rather than `return Successor` in the basis case? Also -- the output you report doesn't match the code you posted.

Comment: I changed the output.

Comment: In addition to having `print` when a `return` makes more sense, you aren't *returning* the result `Function(Number, Successor)` in the recursive branch. Also -- your naming conventions clash with the commonly used [pep style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I changed the code after  according to <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none>. But now the Kernel dies

Comment: If you changed the code and are getting a completely different error, perhaps you could write a new question.