# Python loop and return pattern

Tags: python

I am trying this code.

Function `incre_test` is recursive unless it satisfy the condition.

I expect `5` as result but it returns `None`.

What is the best practice for this pattern?

```
def incre_test(i):
    if i > 4:
        return i
    i = i + 1
    incre_test(i)

res = incre_test(0)
print(res) // why None???
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def incre_test(i):
    while not i == 5:
        i+=1
    return i

res = incre_test(0)
print(res)
```

You have to use a `while <bool>:` loop to run a script (in this case `i+=1`) until the condition given is true.

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop inside the function might do you better

such as

```
def incre_test(i):
    while i < 5:
        i += 1
    return i
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your function is not returning anyting unless the parameter is greater than 4, so all you have to do is to add a `return` statement over the recursive call of the function, like this...

```py
def incre_test(i):
    if i > 4:
        return i
    return incre_test(i+1)

res = incre_test(0)
print(res)
```

Output:-

```
5
```