# Python: recursive function to find value in nested dictionary keeps returning 'None'

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, nested

I have a nested dictionary containing microscopy acquisition metadata that would look like:

```
metadata_dict = {Metadata:   {"_text"       :   "\n\n  ",
                              "Core"        :   [{"_text"   :   \n\n  ",
                                                  "Guid"        :   [{"_text"   :   "c..."}],
                                                  "UserID"      :   [{"_text"   :   "xyz"}]
                                                  "AppSW"       :   [{"_text"   :   "xT"}]
                                                  "AppSWVer"    :   [{"_text"   :   "0"}]
                                                }],
                              "Instrument"  :   [{"_text"   :   "\n\n  ",
                                                  "ContrSWVer   :   [{"_text":  :   "10..."}]
                                                   ...
```

and so forth (hope the indentations make it a bit less chaotic). I only require certain key/value pairs and I'm using python to get the values to specifiable keys. The .get() method returns 'None' no matter the argument, so I tried the following to go over all values in the dictionary to find specific keys:

```py
def lookup(dic,prop):
    for k, v in dic.items():
        if k == prop:
            if not isinstance(v, dict):
                return v
            else:
                for key, value in v:
                    return value
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            lookup(v, prop)
```

Calling this method, e. g. by

```
UserID = lookup(metadata_dict, 'UserID')
print(UserID)
```

I only get 'None' outputs regardless of the level at which the argument is nested in the dictionary.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none) seemed to tackle the same problem, however, after changing the last two lines to

```py
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            return lookup(v, prop)
```

I still get but 'None' returns.
Could this be caused by recursively calling the method with the second argument being *prop* resulting in the method running with *v, prop* (and *prop* being an undefined variable) rather than inheriting the argument (*'UserID'* in the example) from the initial function? If so, why wouldn't this return an error, considering *prop* is undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `UserID` is inside `['Metadata']['Core']` which is a list.

You are only recursing if `v` is a dict.

You could modify your code to handle that:

```
def lookup(dic, prop):
    for k, v in dic.items():
        if k == prop:
            if not isinstance(v, dict):
                return v
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            return lookup(v, prop)
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for item in v:
                found = lookup(item, prop)
                if found:
                    return found
```

```
>>> lookup(metadata_dict, "UserID")
[{'_text': 'xyz'}]
```

I left out:

```
else:
    for key, value in v:
        return value
```

`v` is a dict, so this should raise an error. Also `return` will exit the function - so this will only ever process a single value.

If there can be multiple matches - you could use a generator instead.

```
def lookup(dic, prop):
    for k, v in dic.items():
        if k == prop:
            if not isinstance(v, dict):
                yield v
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from lookup(v, prop)
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for item in v:
                yield from lookup(item, prop)
```

Output:

```
>>> for result in lookup(metadata_dict, "UserID"):
...     print(result)
[{'_text': 'xyz'}]
```

Example with multiple values:

```
>>> for result in lookup({"Foo": [{"UserID": 1}], "Bar": {"Baz":[{"Hi": {"UserID": "2"}}]}}, "UserID"):
...     print(result)
1
2
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense (and was hard to miss in hindsight). The code works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to see if it works, if not, i suggest that you explain the results you want, you can use data as an example

```
def lookup(dic, prop):
    res = []
    for item in dic.values():
        if isinstance(item, list):
            for sub_item in item:
                for k, v in sub_item.items():
                    if k == prop:
                        res.append(v)
        elif isinstance(item, dict):
            for k, v in item.items():
                if k == prop:
                    res.append(v)
    return res


metadata_dict = {"Metadata":   {"_text"       :   "\n\n  ",
                              "Core"        :   [{"_text"   :   "\n\n  ",
                                                  "Guid"        :   [{"_text"   :   "c..."}],
                                                  "UserID"      :   [{"_text"   :   "xyz"}],
                                                  "AppSW"       :   [{"_text"   :   "xT"}],
                                                  "AppSWVer"    :   [{"_text"   :   "0"}]
                                                }],
                              "Instrument"  :   [{"_text"   :   "\n\n  ",
                                                  "Guid"        :   [{"_text"   :   "124"}],
                                                  "UserID"      :   [{"_text"   :   "waefe"}],
                                                  "AppSW"       :   [{"_text"   :   "asfa"}],
                                                  "AppSWVer"    :   [{"_text"   :   "21"}]
                                                }]
}}

print(lookup(metadata_dict["Metadata"], "UserID"))
```