# Python recursive function is not using argument correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just can not wrap my head why this code would not work:

```py
def list_flatten(a_list):
    for item in a_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            list_flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item

print(list(list_flatten([["A"]])))

print(list(list_flatten(["A", ["B"], "C"])))
```

Expecting:

- ["A"] and
- ["A", "B", "C"]

Getting

- [] and
- ["A", "C"]

Side note: Do not want to use chain.from_iterable, because it will breakdown the strings too, like ["123"] might end up ["1","2","3"]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Comment: `list_flatten(item)` creates a new iterator (a generator), nothin is done with it and it is discarded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing anything with the result of your recursive call.

Change

```
list_flatten(item)
```

to

```
yield from list_flatten(item)
```

and you should be good to go. (See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr) for `yield from`.)