# Function is returning NoneType in Python instead of integer

Tags: python, nonetype

```
def function(n):
    if n%4==1:
      return(n**2)
    else:
      n += 1
      function(n)

# Here for example n=6:

if function(6)%2==0:
    print(function(6))
else:
    print("Hey!")
```

This is showing the error **unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'**. I have tried to convert NoneType with int() but that is telling me to give "str" or other data types as an argument.

When I am telling function(n) to return in both 'if' and 'else' conditions, only then it does not show the error.

Comment: it should be ```return function(n)``` not ```function(n)```

Comment: @Nin17 They seem to know that, see their last paragraph.

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive – if you don't return a value, they don't return anything. That is, it works exactly like it would if you called a different function instead of the same one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Comment: What do you expect the function or program to do? Please provide some context, so we can help you achieve your goal.

Comment: What is your question? You've already told us how you can fix it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To elaborate on comments from [Nin17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73041650/function-is-returning-nonetype-in-python-instead-of-integer/73041764#comment129004535_73041650) and [molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73041650/function-is-returning-nonetype-in-python-instead-of-integer/73041764#comment129004544_73041650):

Your function `function(n)` is supposed to return an integer value.
Like you did in `if` branch with `return(n**2)`, do return in the `else` branch:

```
def function(n):
    if n % 4 == 1:
      return n**2
    else:      
      return function(n + 1)  # inlined the increased n and do return
```

I would recommend to give the function a meaningful name.

A function like yours that calls itself is a [*recursive* function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). One of it's key-mechanisms is that it returns a value.

Comment: It's not at all clear what OP is asking, so (almost by definition) this cannot be a useful answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
def function(n):
    if n%4==1:
      return(n**2)
    else:
      n += 1
      return function(n)

if function(6)%2==0:
    print(function(6))
else:
    print("Hey!")
```

in your else statement you return nothing. Put the return statement in there for your recursive function.