# Why my function does not return the list?

Tags: python

The strangest thing is that I place a `print()` just before the `return` and the print does give the values I expect, but then I receive `None`.

```py
class listNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

a = listNode(1)
b = listNode(2)
c = listNode(4)

def convert_to_list_rec(nod, list=[]):
    if nod == None:
        print(list)
        return list
    list.append(nod.val)
    convert_to_list_rec(nod.next, list)


arr = convert_to_list_rec(a)
```

Comment: Did you mean: `return convert_to_list_rec(nod.next, list)`? I think this should be the last line of your recursive function.

Comment: `list` is a reserved word and it looks like you're using it as a variable name? I suspect you're running into a conflict between the system definition of list (a class) and your presumed use of `list` as a variable name. I would rename `list` to something else.

Comment: Can someone close this as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)?

Comment: Using a `list` as a variable name will just give you a headache. And setting a mutable list as an function default argument [will do it even more so](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/).

Comment: Also, it's a bad idea to rely on recursion in python. This probably should be a simple iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return from the recursive call, see this example:

```
class listNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next


a = listNode(1)
a.next = listNode(2)
a.next.next = listNode(4)


def convert_to_list_rec(nod, res):
    if not nod:
        return res
    return convert_to_list_rec(nod.next, res + [nod.val])


arr = convert_to_list_rec(a, [])

print(arr)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 4]
```