# my Binary Search program return None always instead of returning Index value or -1

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search

I am trying to find a target value from a list but its returning None Instead of returning (index value or -1)

```
class Solution:
    def search(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        ub=len(nums)-1
        lb=0
        length=lb+ub
        flag=0
        def find(nums,lb,ub,length,target):
            mid=length//2
            if(lb>ub):
                return -1
            elif(target==nums[mid]):
                return mid
            elif(target<=nums[mid]):
                ub=mid-1
                length=lb+ub
                find(nums,lb,ub,length,target)
            elif(target>=nums[mid]):
                lb=mid+1
                length=lb+ub
                find(nums,lb,ub,length,target)
        find(nums,lb,ub,length,target)
```

Output **None**

I know there were other solutions but can't understand what causes this error right now

Comment: It May be a little funny We can easily solve this problem by four lines of code      [   if target in nums:
            return nums.index(target)
        
        elif target not in nums:
            return -1 ]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 3):

add `return` before every call to the `find` function