# python recursion problem TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I know how to debug it but i just want to know why we see this error

```
def sum1(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    n+sum1(n-1)



print(sum1(5))
```

```
 File "C:\Users\LENOVO\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\cc\hello\sum of first n number.py", line 4, in sum1
    n+sum1(n-1)
  [Previous line repeated 1 more time]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

to calculate sum of n number in python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

Answer (score 0):

as you have mentioned n value is 5. when we call sum1 function with n value 5 .it is not returning anything. so it is taking None Type .you can apply return keyword before function recursion like this. it will work

```
n+sum1(n-1)# 5 --->int +sum1(5-1)---> returns none type.

def sum1(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    return n+sum1(n-1)



print(sum1(10))
```

Comment: @kishan singh. did you get it?