# How come the global variable is not returned despite keyword global being used

Tags: python

I have accessed a global variable called `counter` using the keyword `global` however the function does not return the global variable. Oddly, `print` works but not `return`.

FYI: The function below is recursive and is supposed to take as input any integer and output the number of steps required to reduce it to 0, depending on whether it's odd or even at each iteration.

```
counter = 0
def number_of_steps(num):
    global counter
    if num == 0:
        return(counter)
    elif num % 2 == 0:
        num = num / 2
        counter += 1
        number_of_steps(num)
    else: 
        num -= 1
        counter += 1
        number_of_steps(num)
 
number_of_steps(2) #expect => 2, but actually get NoneType
```

Comment: You forgot to recursively return number_of_steps(nums) in both elif and else

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out by @tripleee this is a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372/why-does-my-recursive-function-return-none)

In short, Python implicitly returns `None` if a return statement is not added.