# See if value exists in Python nested dict which contains dicts, lists, and strings

Tags: python, recursion

I'm not sure if there is some library that handles this, or if recursion is the way to go. I am trying to write a recursion function, when I call it it always ends up returning `False`. Any help appreciated.

`item` starts out as a dict.
`text` is a string to match.

```
def match(item, text):
    if item == text:
        return True
    if type(item) == list:
        for i in item:
            match(i, text)
    if type(item) == dict:
        for i in item.values():
             match(i text)
    return False
```

I'm not quite grasping how to have it keep going when say the first item of a list is not a match.

Comment: Your function always returns `False` -- `return False`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not returning `True` when the recursive call finds a match.

```
def match(item, text):
    if item == text:
        return True
    if isinstance(item, (list, tuple)):
        return any(match(i, text) for i in item)
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        return any(match(i, text) for i in item.values())
    return False
```

You should also use `isinstance()` for type checks, to allow for subclasses.

Comment: I am out of close votes today, but you should know well by now that this is a common duplicate: the canonical is [Why does my recursive function return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778372).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No, it's not as simple as the usual `return recursive_call(...)`, because additional logic is needed with the result of the recursive calls.

Comment: Aside from the part where you know that a question with multiple problems is too broad, we have canonicals for that, too.